# Json encode data looping in js

Tags: javascript

I have data that php returned to JS but i dunno how to loop it to access the information... i have this:

```
    result = call_data('get_chat.php');
            console.log(result);
    for(var data in result){

        alert(result[data]["id"]); //says undefined

    }
```

Console Log shows:

```
   [{"eventtime":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","message":"test2","bywho":"dave","id":"2"},
    {"eventtime":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","message":"testttt","bywho":"dave","id":"1"}]
```

So i want to loop each data from it but how do i do it im really confused!! It just says undefined each time.

Comment: What does `console.log(typeof result);` say?

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/javascript-for-in-with-arrays

Comment: @JonathanLonowski it just says "string"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `typeof result === "string"`, then you still need to parse the response before you can iterate over it:

```
result = JSON.parse(call_data('get_chat.php'));
```

Then, as others have pointed out, you should use a simple `for` loop with `Array`s:

```
for (var i = 0, l = result.length; i < l; i++) {
    console.log(result[i]["id"]);
}
```

`for..in` loops will iterate all enumerable keys rather than just indexes.

Comment: Damn it was json parse i missed! Forgot about that! good spot sir!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your php code returns an array of objects, so you need to first iterate through the array, and then access the `id` key like so:

```
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
  var obj = result[i];
  console.log(obj.id); // this will be the id that you want
  console.log(obj["id"]); // this will also be the id  
}
```

Comment: result.length = 166 how ever... (typeof) for result is "string" =/

Comment: @Dave That's because as Jonathon pointed out, it's a json string so calling `length` on it will return the number of characters in the string. Pass it to `JSON.parse` first.